# Coded Value Domains in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, esri-geodatabase, domains

I am analyzing a database in ArcMap 10.1 and I wanted to know whether it is possible to trace what tables are linked to a particular Coded Value Domain? I am attempting to find a particular table.

I know that you can do this the other way around and look at what Coded Value Domains are being assigned to a table but as the database is soo large this isn't particularly useful.

Any suggestions would be helpful, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with arcpy. I usually use arcpy.da.ListDomains to iterate through the domains but in your case you just need to see if there are any domains assigned to a field in feature classes. This code can iterate really quickly through multiple feature classes and report those that have a field that has been assigned to the domain you've specified.

```
import arcpy    
gdb = r"C:\GIS\SDE_DB_CURRENT_SNAPSHOT.gdb" #supply the geodatabase path
arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
domain_to_search = r"CodedValuesCountries" #supply the CV domain name

fcs_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in fcs_list:
    #print fc
    fc_fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
    for field in fc_fields:
        #print field.domain
        if field.domain == domain_to_search:
            print "feature class that uses this domain is", fc
```

This code can be run from Python window in ArcGIS, as a script tool or from an IDLE or IDE such as PyScripter.

Comment: I'm sorry I am quite new to Python, could you please highlight the sections/text that I would need to modify for my own purposes? Thanks.

Comment: @Canningmister, I've edited the code with comments. Let us know if you've managed to run it and works for you.

Comment: I believe this works, however it's not showing any results so maybe I haven't got the file path for the database correct?

Comment: Could be. Update your question with all relevant details then please.